# Replace getMap with getMapAsync with custom support fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

trying to update my google dependencies from 9.0.0 to 15.0.0. But I have to update

```
getMap();
```

with

```
getMapAsync();
```

Because getMap(); is deprecated in newest versions of google libraries.

The issue is I am using custom fragment to load the view. I am doing it this way because I have 3 different map types that can be loaded into the map view based on user selection. But it's not letting me do getMapAsync without error.

Here is my code:

```
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    if (mMapFragment == null) {
        mMapFragment = new CustomSupportMapFragment(); 

        mMapFragment.setOnMapCreatedListener(new CustomSupportMapFragment.MapViewCreatedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMapCreated() {
                boolean needUpdate = mMap == null;
                mMap = mMapFragment.getMapAsync();

                if (mMap != null)
                    setUpMap(needUpdate);
            }
        });

    }

    FragmentTransaction ft = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.map, mMapFragment);
    ft.commit();
}
```

But I am getting error:

```
getMapAsync (OnMapReadyCallback) in SupportMapFragment cannot be applied to ()
```

So I tried adding **this**, **getContext()** in like this:

```
getMapAsync(this);

getMapAsync(getContext));
```

but both come back with errors about it cannot be applied.

Any ideas? Sorry for my understanding of java is new and I am learning. I tried searching StackOverflow and google already for this issue but can only find resolutions when using regular supportmapfragment and not custom supportmapfragment.

Here is my setUpMap method if it helps for you to understand:

```
private void setUpMap(boolean needUpdate) {
    boolean location_permission_granted = (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    if (!location_permission_granted) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 200);
    } else {
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }

    mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {

            if (LOAD_PARTICULAR_MAP == 1) {
                if (cameraPosition.zoom > AppConstants.MAX_ZOOM) {
                    CameraUpdate upd = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(cameraPosition.target, AppConstants.MAX_ZOOM);
                    mMap.moveCamera(upd);
                }


                float maxZoom = 4f;
                if (cameraPosition.zoom > maxZoom) {
                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(maxZoom));
                    return;
                }
                float minZoom = 0f;
                if (cameraPosition.zoom < minZoom) {
                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(minZoom));
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    });
    mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
    mMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this);
    mMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
    mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(this);
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
//        mBtnMapType.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    mMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(true);

    //mBtnLegend.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    //updateLegendButton();
    updateMapType(mSettings.getMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN));
    /*mTileProvider = new TranslucentUrlTileProvider(AppConstants.SERVER_URL, AppConstants.SERVER_URL_FREE);
//        mTileProvider.setPro(!mIsPro.showPurchaseDialog());
    //mTileProvider.setOpacity(mOpacity);
    mTileOverlay = mMap.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(mTileProvider));*/
    if (needUpdate)
        if (LOAD_PARTICULAR_MAP != 4) {
            gotoMyLocation();
        }
//        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener()       {
//            @Override
//            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
//                if (marker != null) {
//                    openGoogleMap(marker);
//                    return true;
//                }
//                return false;
//            }
//        });

    switch (LOAD_PARTICULAR_MAP) {

        case 1:

            auroraOverMap();
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(0f));

            break;

        case 2:

            lightPollutionMap();

            break;

        case 3:

            loadCloudMap();

            break;

        case 4:

            highestValueView();
//                mMap.animateCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo( 12f )    );

            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: not sure why downvote and no one can help :(
I was going to send donation to anyone that can help me fix it. Way to keep up the spirit of helping the community guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get [`GoogleMap`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap) object by calling

```
mMap = mMapFragment.getMapAsync();
```

you should use code like that:

```
mMapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
    }
});
```

where `mMap` is global variable:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    ...
```

and after you got `mMap` you can use it for setup your map:

```
mMapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        if (mMap != null)
                setUpMap(needUpdate);
    }
});
```

Also, take a look at [Official Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start?hl=en).

Comment: ok ill try it and let you know thank you for answer :) i keep you updated